# Current Sources - Usage and Projects

Tags: current-source

I came across this page on [building your own current source](http://users.telenet.be/davshomepage/current-source.htm).

What are current sources used for in real-world applications?  The only places I've seen them used are textbooks.

Do you have any suggestions for some fun weekend projects involving a current source?

Comment: Is there any real world current sources? How can I implement a current source from a voltage source?

Comment: Well, it looks like you've read just textbooks up to now. They are used quite a lot "in real world".

Comment: Likely you don't know that one interesting application in the "power real world" are CCR's (constant current regulators) used to power airfield lights (on runways and taxiways). The rms value of the ac output current is constant in this case.

Answer (score 9):

The page you point to uses a current source to drive an LED which is a very popular
real-world application and is also a good weekend project ;)
The color temperature of the LEDs changes with current so keeping the current 
constant is useful for some applications.

- Current sources can also be used in battery charging applications where you
  need to maintain a constant current to properly charge a particular chemistry 
  of battery.
- I have used current sinks to test power supplies. A typically power supply test
  will be to run the power supply at it's rated current to verify proper voltage
  regulation.
- Your multimeter may use a current source to measure resistance. Pass a current
  through an unknown resistance and measure a voltage.
- Within circuits a current source (and sink) can be used to bias transistors (like
  a differential amplifier circuit).

Comment: Specifically, I know lead-acid batteries require a constant current source (or current-limited source, depending on your perspective) to charge them up to a certain voltage, after which they use a constant voltage charge.  http://www.batteryuniversity.com/partone-13.htm

Answer (score 4):

Stepper motor drivers are constant current sources made by switching the motor windings on and off at high-frequency. They monitor the current on sense resistors and adjust the duty cycle appropriately.

If you want some examples of the loosy (not switch-mode) kind then Ethernet and CAN use simple resistor current sources and current mirror circuits to limit the current spikes and reduce EMI when transmitting.

Another example are laser diode power supplies. The diodes are extremely sensitive to over-currents and have a sharp U(I) characteristic at the operating point. Even small fluctuations in voltage can cause large currents and destroy the diode.

One more example is the diode testing mode of a multimeter. It will source a little more than 1mA to allow you to check diode and transistor polarity and forward voltages.

PS. All these examples are really constant current/constant voltage since their maximum output voltage is limited by the power supply voltage. In fact both kinds of real sources have a limit: current sources won't work if the load resistance is too high and voltage sources won't work if the load resistance is too low.

Answer (score 3):

Solar cells behave like current sources-- their voltage remains relatively constant across different light levels, while the current changes roughly linearly. I've seen current sources used in solar call testing before.

LED brightness is proportional to current, so if you made an adjustable current source, you could make a dimmable LED flashlight-- that would be pretty cool.

Comment: If solar cell voltage remains constant how can the current change? You must be thinking about some kind of smart switching-mode load since this would not be possible with normal resistive loads.

Comment: You are correct-- solar panels generally feed into a power tracking circuit that varies its impedance with a switching element to maximize the power extracted from the panel.

Comment: solar cell voltage is related to the band-gap in the semiconductor material the cell is made of. photons at or above the band gap energy cause electron-hole pairs to form in the junction, and the field from the lattice drives these in opposite directions, supplying the current. so the voltage is related to the material, relatively constant, and the current depends on the number of suitably energetic photons striking the cell, so the available current is related to the amount of illumination. fwiw, i'd say this makes a solar cell a more of a voltage source, not a current source.

Answer (score 3):

Current sources are used to [linearize transistor amplifiers](http://www.zen22142.zen.co.uk/Design/config2.htm), and as I understand it are used all over the place [inside of ICs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier#Internal_circuitry_of_741_type_op-amp).

Comment: Analog IC design uses a LOT of current references. Both bipolar transistors as well as CMOS transistors are very current dependent. Current references, as well as current mirrors are extremely common because so many things are current dependent. With bias current through an amplifier or other circuit you can control power consumption, bandwidth, slew rate, and much more. This is not the case in digital circuits, as the fine control over a transistor that a current reference offers is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Many sensors and transducers out there are easy to instrument with constant current sources. RTDs are the first thing that come to mind, but really any resistive based transducer can be driven with a constant current source and then all you need to do is monitor the voltage drop across the element with something like an instrumentation amplifier to measure its output.

Like endolith mentioned, current sources are very important in many IC's, especially analog IC's including, amplifiers, op-amps, digital-to-analog converters. If I am remembering my basic amplifier design correctly constant current sources are common in the input stages of many designs to ensure proper biasing in the input FETs or BJTs.

Answer (score 2):

Op-amps often (always?) use a current-source driven differential amplifier as the input stage, and it is this that confers the high-impedance to the input of the op-amp.

A current source provides a fixed current, regardless of the voltage across it. So the impedance of a current source is the ratio of change in voltage divided by the resulting change in current. Since for a current source, current doesn't change, the ideal current source therefore has infinite impedance. Real world current sources do pretty well, 10's of megohms being easily achieved.